# Change RowSource with hidden worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

How do I display/change the available options of a ComboBox while the WorkBook is hidden?

I'm using Excel to create and present a UserForm which is initiated by a Start-button on the first sheet (Name: Menu, CodeName: Menu).

After loading the UserForm I only want to hide the Excel Workbook that is running the VBA code. If/when there is another instance/workbook of Excel opened I dont want the 2nd workbook to hide.

In the UserForm there are several ComboBoxes that display options.
The available options are stored on Sheet1 (Name: inputparameters, CodeName: Sheet1) and the rowsource of the ComboBox are referencing to a range of cells on Sheet1 (i.e. inputparameters!A2:A4). The options change based upon the choice of other ComboBoxes, so I need to change the RowSource when the selection of a ComboBox changes.

Issue: when workbook is hidden the ComboBox options disappear, as if Sheet1 doesn't exist.

When I'm in Debug (with workbook hidden) I can access and retrieve the value of a single cell, but not from a range.

Is there a different/better approach to do this?

Comment: I wouldn't use `Rowsource` at all. I'd assign the range value to the list property of the control - e.g. `me.comboboxname.list = thisworkbooks.sheets("inputparameters".Range("A2:A4").value`

Comment: Please clarify what the meaning of `ComboBox options disappear`. Is there any run-time errors when you try to upate it with VBA code?